# In "Я скажу тебе всё позднее.", what is the grammatical form of всё?

Tags: грамматика, склонение

Is it an adverb, pronoun, or something else?

If it's a declension of весь, which case and gender is it in here?

Comment: Yes, it is neutral gender, singular, accusative case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this sentence *всё* is a pronoun. While English speakers use *all* in place of an adjective and *everything* in place of a noun, in Russian *всё* may stand for both (BTW. English *All*, as a noun only, corresponds to *Все* in Russian).

As Russian pronouns do decline, *всё* is a neutral gender singular of *весь* in both Nominative and Accusative.

Comment: When you say that всё is "in both Nominative and Accusative", you mean in general and not in the example sentence, yes?

Comment: @ycele Yes, in general. Here it's accusative, of course.