# 'all of the' vs 'all the' : using весь

Tags: местоимения, genitive-partitive, притяжательные-местоимения

I want to say,

```
Almost all of the weeds are in bloom.
```

which, in English, can also be stated (improperly?) as,

```
Almost all the weeds are in bloom.
```

So far is that correct?

---

I think these two would translate as,

```
Почти все сорняков (pl. gen.) в цвету.
```

and,

```
Почти все сорняки (pl. nom.) в цвету.
```

---

So my question might originate in which is proper to say in English, but also - for the essence of the idea - which is proper to say in Russian.

The issue being expressed in the title....

This was close, but still did not clarify my question:

[In "Я скажу тебе всё позднее.", what is the grammatical form of всё?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/11301/6545)

**I think** все here in my question is also a pronoun, not an adjective.... correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say either:

> Почти все из сорняков в цвету

or

> Почти все сорняки в цвету

Those are quite close in meaning, but the former can clarify the meaning when the noun is uncountable.

---

> Весь персонал я знаю лично // I know all the staff personally

Here, *персонал* is a synecdoche for "any single person of the staff", because you cannot know groups of people personally.

> Весь персонал весит менее 200 килограмм // All the staff weigh(s) less than 200 kg

This is an ambiguous sentence: is *персонал* a synecdoche for "any single person of the staff" or a literal description for "all of the staff together"? Can we put all the staff into the passenger elevator or should we use the freight one?

> Все из персонала весят менее 200 килограмм // All of the staff weigh less than 200 kg

We'd better wait for the freight one.

---

You can use it even with the countable nouns (like in your example), in which case it means you're talking about smaller classes rather than individual units of the class:

> Почти все сорняки (*900 особей из 1000*) сейчас в цвету.

> Почти все из сорняков (*василёк, полынь, дурман, но не ромашка*) сейчас в цвету.

Comment: Все из sounds awkward to my ear, like a stylistic error. I would expect каждый из there. Not sure if there is a rule though

Comment: @Curiosity sure, but that's not what the op was asking about

Comment: I'm still trying to understand your answer, but... how did you know to use a preposition, из? I think prepositions are usually dictated by verbs, but not here... Maybe the answer is here:  https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/16617/recap-of-%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7

Comment: "Все из них" - a very common structure. "Все из <subjects>" - less common, but still fully grammatical.

Comment: @nate, "из" has the most common meaning "out of", i.e. subclass or part of something. Which is what you need. Sometimes corresponds to "from", but it's the same idea. "2 из 3" = "2 [out] of 3"; "Алекс из Москвы" = "Alex from Moscow" = of all Alexes, the one from Moscow. Just saying все/некоторые/etc. + gen. is ungrammatical: you either use nom. or из + gen, with the subtle difference between them that Quassnoi tried to explain.

Comment: Usually _особи_ we say about anymals, about plants we say _видов_. _(Более 900 видов из 1000)_.

Comment: @elena_m: *особь* ("organism, specimen") and *вид* ("species") are different words meaning different things

Comment: yes, i agree with you that it is different words. But: В энциклопедическом словаре говорится: _Особь - (индивидуум) (от лат. individuum - **неделимое**), **наименее неделимая** единица биологического вида. Для колониальных, вегетативно размножающихся и симбиотических организмов понятие "особь" относительно._ Вы можете взять куст фиалок и **разделить** его на несколько кустов. или отрезать лист и посадить его и вырастет новое растение. либо можно отрезать ус клубники и посадить. у многих растений трудно выделить неделимую часть в отличие от животных.